# SFINAE unexpected result

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, type-traits

Try to understand SFINAE.

```
template <class T, class T1 = void>
struct foo
{
    static constexpr char* a = "primary definition\n";
};

struct A
{
};

template <class T>
struct foo<T, std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, A>::value>::type>
{
    static constexpr char* a = "secondary definition\n";
};
```

Compiler gcc-4.8.1 gives an error

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list
>   for ‘template struct foo’  struct foo::value>::type>

Comment: You're missing a `typename`.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about dependent name

Comment: http://ideone.com/AroOJu

Comment: @0x499602D2 Make that an answer, or find an appropriate duplicate ..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not sure I follow. A vote option for what? :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Forget about it. Too late for my brain, just a silly thing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **C++11 Standard: 14.6/3**
>
> When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1) and its *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be prefixed by the keyword `typename` forming a *typename-specifier*.

`T` is a dependent type, so the `typename` keyword is required:

```
struct foo<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, A>::value>::type>
//            ^^^^^^^^
```

There's also a helper template provided in C++14 that is an alias returning the type:

```
struct foo<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, A>::value>>
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```